# Present Perfect, American English and "since"

Tags: american-english, british-english, tenses, present-perfect

I'm wondering: I was always taught at school  that when using "since", you always have to use Present Perfect (BrE), e.g.

> Since when have you played chess?

But is

> Since when did you play chess?

acceptable in AmE? Which option would the AmE speakers rather use?

Comment: You were apparently taught 1950's grammar; both AmE and BrE usage are changing. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Since+when+did+you%3Aeng_us_2012%2CSince+when+have+you%3Aeng_us_2012%2CSince+when+did+you%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CSince+when+have+you%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSince%20when%20did%20you%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSince%20when%20have%20you%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSince%20when%20did%20you%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSince%20when%20have%20you%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Those don’t sound very normal — at all. “How long have you been playing chess?” or “When did you start playing chess?” is what people would actually say. *Since* is simply not a good starting-word for a question in English these days.

Comment: @tchrist: in the Northeast, if you see somebody playing chess and are quite surprised because you hadn't realized that he played, *"Since when did **you** play chess?"* is a perfectly normal (although definitely informal and slightly rude) remark.

Comment: @PeterShor Your example was indeed the only exception I could think of, and yes, it sounds a bit rude. It has a tone of disbelief or astonishment in it.

Comment: I agree with @tchrist, but will complicate it further; in AmE, it's not uncommon to use *since when* with the present tense to indicate time: *Since when do you play chess?* To which the answer (with since) would be "I've been playing since college" or (without since) "I've been playing for about 5 years." It expresses surprise and is a bit presumptious, but not at all uncommon.

Comment: @tchrist: And looking at the hits from the Ngram for my comment above, it looks like most (if not all) of the increase in *"since when did you"* is the informal usage we are discussing above (this is synonymous to *"since when do you"*, by the way).

Comment: The OP's examples sound normal to me. They would be appropriate when the speaker is surprised to discover that the addressee actually does play chess. The first version with present-perfect would be the "cleaner" sounding version, but the second version could be heard in an informal setting among friends. (Me, an AmE speaker.) And I've actually heard stuff like that.

Comment: As @medica says, *do you* is very common. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+when+have+you%2C+since+when+did+you%2C+since+when+do+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csince%20when%20have%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20when%20did%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csince%20when%20do%20you%3B%2Cc0) has them all in a dead heat.

Comment: @bib - If you tweak the ngram to refer only to British English, _since when have you_ seems significantly ahead of the other two, though less so than forty or fifty years ago.

Comment: In BrE, we would commonly say "since when DO you play chess?" if surprised to see someone playing chess, and we would say "since when HAVE you playED chess" if it were a genuine question.

Comment: @MattGutting And if you tweak it for AmE, the present tense creeps ahead.

Comment: @medica: so in the answer you'd always use the continuous tense. And do you, AmE speakers, always use Present Perfect with since in declarative sentences (e.g. I've been playing (or played?) the guitar since 2005)?

Comment: I, a native AmE speaker, have used present perfect with "since" in declarative sentences since I began speaking. ;)  I would probably never begin a question with "Since when..." unless I'm making a presumptuous (and somewhat impolite) expression of surprise or doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally means "I did not realize you ever played chess".  As 'Since when do you paint?" means that I am dubious that you paint.

So it happens, but it is a strange idiom and not normal usage that follows the standard definitions.